# join/combine similar columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have this problem after I merged/combined multiple columns:

```
df = 
Name    id  id_x    id_y    age age_x
A   111 111     20  
B   112     112     30
C       113 113 40  40
```

My goal is to clean them up like this:

```
Name    id  age
A   111 20
B   112 30
C   113 40
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0],1).first()
Out[1196]: 
  Name   age     id
0    A  20.0  111.0
1    B  30.0  112.0
2    C  40.0  113.0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use `fillna`

```
df1.fillna(df2)
```

If those are truly spaces

```
df1.mask(df1.astype(str).eq(‘’), df2)
```

Comment: I don't want to say where I was when I answered this.  But I'm looking at the part of the question where OP stated they had merged dataframes.  From the resulting dataframe `df`, it looks as though they had two dataframes joined on index.  I could be wrong and will likely delete the answer.